# Rake Task Ordering

Tags: ruby, rake

Suppose I have two top-level tasks:

```
task :publicBuild => [:zipSourceCode, :copyPrivateKey]
task :internalBuild => [:copyPrivateKey]
```

For the `internalBuild` task, I don't want to zip source code - I just want the private key. But for a `publicBuild`, I want to do both. But I need to guarantee that for the `publicBuild`, the `zipSourceCode` task is executed before the `copyPrivateKey` task (I don't want the source code ZIP to contain the public key).

A dependency such as `copyPrivateKey => zipSourceCode` wouldn't work because it would mean that for `internalBuild`, it would call `zipSourceCode`, which I don't want.

What I want to tell rake is "if these two tasks are to be executed, you should do this one first, but they are both optional". Is this possible?

Comment: It doesn't run them in the order you specify them in the array?  That's surprising, since arrays are ordered in Ruby...and I can't find any questions like this around the net, which is equally surprising, since it seems totally implausible that no one else would have run into this issue...

Comment: It does run them in the order - I just didn't expect I could rely on that order. Perhaps I should have read the documentation more thoroughly. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As floyd said... the tasks should be performed in the order in which they appear in the dependency array.

Comment: ... so long as `:zipSourceCode` doesn't depend on a task that in turn depends on `:copyPrivateKey`. That would cause them to get run in the wrong order when Rake resolves the dependencies.